# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2013,2015 SP15 OR Older for VS2013

Tags: visual-studio

could anyone kindly assist me in finding a download link for Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 SP15 or older? I've been searching on the official site, but it seems that only SP18 is available. I specifically require SP15 or an older version. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've been searching on the official site, but it seems that only SP18 is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it [here](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html). You have to select the product and version from the dropdown.

The above link and versions is references in the [SAP wiki](https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/crystalreports/3354091173.html)